# How to make a button control visible on mouse over in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008, user-controls

I have a requirement, where on a window my button control is invisible, but when the user accidently hovers his mouse on that area the button gets visible. Kind of like an Easter Egg. Below is my code for the XAML but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<Button Margin="0,0,20,0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        Name="CopyText" Width="75" Height="25">
    <Button.Style>         
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Style.Triggers>                 
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"> 
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>     
    </Button.Style> 
</Button>
```

Comment: when stting default visibility to true, you see the button ?

Comment: Yes I do see the button in that case.

Comment: Do you see a MouseEnter property in the properties window? That's what I always do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `ControlTemplate` with a border having transparent background + invisible button within. Then  on mouse over border you can set visibility of button to Visible.

MSDN says some interestin things about visibility : 
Elements where Visibility is not Visible do not participate in input events (or commands), do not influence either the Measure or Arrange passes of layout, are not in a tab sequence, and will not be reported in hit testing.

That explains the behaviour you noticed.

Then in case you write a `ControlTemplate`, the button not hidding again after click
might be because it has focus : it would make some sense that a focused element can't 
be set invisible. I'd try make it loose focus in click handler (focus on smthg else).

Comment: I tried doing that. But the button doesnt not become transparent again after once clicking on it, unless I click somewhere else.

Comment: Try adding another trigger, where IsMouseOver is false? I believe IsMouseOver is treated more like an event rather than a normal property.

Comment: same question, in fact ( :-) ) : did you set both the trigger when IsMouseOver is true and when IsMouseOver is false ?